# MsBuild: Read part of the file using ReadLinesFromFile

Tags: msbuild

I need to read the XML from the file. I use following code:

```
<ItemGroup>
<SourceXsltFile Include="SourceFile.xml" />
</ItemGroup>

<ReadLinesFromFile File="@(SourceXsltFile)">
  <Output TaskParameter="Lines" ItemName="FileContents" />
</ReadLinesFromFile>
```

But I need only the part of the file's content to be copied which resides inside the `<XSL>` tag.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/ - use RegexMatch task with something like - `<XSL\b[^>]*>(.*?)</XSL>` (not sure about exact correctness though).
- Write your own custom task

Answer (score 2):

In 4.0+ there are XmlPeek, XmlPoke, and XslTransform tasks you can use here. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff598688.aspx).